# COUNT and COUNT DISTINCT for different groups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

For a SQL Server based report,

Table:

```
CID   Date     ID   Service    Days
1   3/7/2016    1   Individual  3
2   4/5/2016    2   Individual  4
3   5/24/2016   1   Individual  3
4   4/4/2016    4   Group       2
5   4/4/2016    4   Group       2
6   2/18/2016   4   Group       2
7   5/5/2016    5   Group       1
8   5/5/2016    5   Group       1
```

I used this code:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    Service,
    COUNT(WHEN Days = 4 THEN 1 END) AS '4Days',
    COUNT(WHEN Days = 3 THEN 1 END) AS '3Days',
    COUNT(WHEN Days = 2 THEN 1 END) AS '2Days',
    COUNT(WHEN Days = 1 THEN 1 END) AS '1Day'

    FROM Table T1
    GROUP BY
    ID,
    Service
```

which gives me this Output:

```
ID  Service      4Days   3Days    2Days  1Day
1   Individual     0       2       0      0
2   Individual     1       0       0      0
4   Group          0       0       3      0
5   Group          0       0       0      2
```

What I want to do is not count the Group services as separate services for separate individuals, but just as one service per group. A Count Distinct used with the Date or ID could help me do that but I don't know how to make that play with the Individual services where I just wanna count them individually and not using DISTINCT. So the desired output is:

```
ID  Service      4Days   3Days    2Days  1Day
1   Individual     0       2       0      0
2   Individual     1       0       0      0
4   Group          0       0       2      0
5   Group          0       0       0      1
```

I'll edit the post in case I oversimplified the problem since this is dummy data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could use `distinct` this way if you wanted:

```
count(distinct
    case when Days = 1 then case when Service = 'Group' then 1 else "Date" end end
) as [1Day]
```

Depending on your indexing it's possible that introducing another column in the query would change the query plan. I suspect that probably isn't the case though.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last edit, this is the most straight forward way I could think of to handle the query:

```
with cte as (
  select id, service, days
    from table t1
   where service = 'Individual'
   union all
  select id, service, days
    from table t1
   where service = 'Group'
   group by id, service, days, date
)
select id,
       service,
       count(case when days = 4 then 'X' end) as [4Days],
       count(case when days = 3 then 'X' end) as [3Days],
       count(case when days = 2 then 'X' end) as [2Days],
       count(case when days = 1 then 'X' end) as [1Day]
  from cte
 group by id, service
```

Comment: You could just use `sign()` instead of the inner `case`s. It's a little shorter.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong for '2Days' column service type 'Group' count should be '2' if our grouping based on 'Date' column, if so then try this:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    Service,
    CASE WHEN MAX(t.days) = 4 THEN MAX(t.date) ELSE 0 END AS '4Days',
    CASE WHEN MAX(t.days) = 3 THEN MAX(t.date) ELSE 0 END AS '3Days',
    CASE WHEN MAX(t.days) = 2 THEN MAX(t.date) ELSE 0 END AS '2Days',
    CASE WHEN MAX(t.days) = 1 THEN MAX(t.date) ELSE 0 END AS '1Day'
FROM table T1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT days, 
                 COUNT(DISTINCT(date)) date 
             FROM Table WHERE days = t1.days GROUP BY days) t
GROUP BY id, service
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Updated Date for CID=6 and Desired output for 2Days column = 2 since they are 2 different group services, signified by the different dates